# Tracking participants leaving window

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am implementing in Qualtrics a task where participants could easily look up answers to questions. Given this, I was wondering if anyone out there knows a way to track this. I'm looking for an option to find out subjects who leave the window of survey.

I tried to do this without success using such a code:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
 window.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
  
  }, true);
});
```

I don't really care how the function will work, I just want to know if subjects leave the window. It could be a function which count how long a subject has been out the window, a function that count how much times s.he leave the window, or even gives the minimal information - leaved / didn't leave.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hidden#Browser_compatibility

Comment: `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() 
{                                                    
 var RAT1 = Boolean(("${e://Field/RAT1}"))                 
 document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
    console.log(document.hidden);
                                                 RAT1 = document.hidden;
  Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('RAT1',RAT1);
 })
});` I tried this, but it is not working. Maybe you know why?